# How do I run an individual testthat test in R?

Tags: r, testthat

I want to use [testthat](https://github.com/hadley/testthat) for integration tests in an R package being installed into a Jupyter notebook environment. Practically, that means I don't want the tests run when the package is installed, but rather manually later, when the system is running.

I think that means I shouldn't put tests into a `tests/testthat` directory, but rather the R directory.

So, I still want all the expect_ functions, but how do I run a test? I'm not sure if I can specify a file or directory, because it will be after the package is installed, and I don't know what the current working directory or install directory will be.

Comment: I may have misunderstood, but the tests don't run when a package is installed.

Comment: Thanks. Are you suggesting I put things in tests, and use the test_package facility? It just feels a bit weird. Integration tests don't feel like unit tests. Unit tests require no components set up, but integration tests require (indeed are testing) database connections, etc.

Answer (score 0):

From the `testthat` package . . .

> If you're using testthat in a package, you should put your tests in
>   tests/testthat. Each test file should start with test and end in .R or
>   .r. To ensure R CMD check runs your tests, place the following code in
>   tests/testthat.R:
>
> library(testthat) ;
>   library(yourpackage)
>
> test_check("yourpackage")

It sounds like you should follow all the setup but leave the `testthat.R` file out of the directory. You can run the `test_check("yourpackage")` from the console or a script.

Comment: I think it might be that the code in 'tests' is not installed with the package. So, I think this doesn't work. :/

Comment: Most packages I have seen have a 'tests' directory. This seems to be a requirement in order to get loaded onto CRAN. However if there is not a 'tests' directory there is nothing for `testthat` to do and will return something like "No tests found"

Comment: I built the package with a tests directory and a test_x.R, installed it, but then when I loaded the package and asked it to run the package tests, there were none. I concluded that as the library is installed, it strips the tests. But, maybe I am wrong and I missed something else setting it up. I'll look. If you can try it as well, that would help.

Comment: You are right it looks like the package build strips the test directory out. You could add some tests in the documentation or as an example but it would have to be in the main directory tree.  A bit of a bummer if you ask me.